# Scale data to a certain range

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have an implementation question about how to scale the data into certain range. I know using the below equation we can scale the data:

```
X_nor = ((b-a)*(X-min))/((max-min)+a)
```

where a,b is the range that I want to scale(e.g. -1,1). And the max and min are the maximum number and minimum number in original data. X is the original data and X_nor is normalized data.

My question is: suppose I have three data, each shape is (1,128,128,1). And I use the above equation to do normalization, are the max and min the maximum and minimum number of the three data or each individual data?

To say it clear, the code above is what I said the max and min for the whole data:

```
max=0
min=0
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i].max()>max:
        max=data[i].max()
     if data[i].min()<min:
        min=data[i].min()
```

And the code below is what I said individual max and min:

```
max=[]
min=[]
for i in range(len(data)):
    max.append(data[i].max())
    min.append(data[i].min())
```

In this way, when doing normalization, the data will minus its own max and min, but not the unique max and min in the first situation.

Another question is: In this way, will the features or patterns in the original data be destroyed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think your formula should be X_nor = (((b-a)*(X-min))/(max-min))+a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. Both of them are right. When dealing with images, the second method (channel-wise normalization) is the most common technique. And while doing normalization, we just rescale the data and hence the original features and patterns are not destroyed. You can always go back to the original scale if you want to after normalization.